# datagrid it is not showing in TabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a ajaxtoolkit:TabContainer in my code. I put gridview inside it. but it is not showing the grid view when I run the project. gridview is fine and is showing data when it is not inside the TabContainer.

This is my aspx code:

```
            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tbAgency" runat="server" HeaderText="Agency"  >
                   <ContentTemplate>
                       <asp:GridView ID="grAgency" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                                                                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                                 Width="901px" style="cursor: pointer;" AllowPaging="True" 
                                                                 AllowSorting="True" PageSize="20">
                                                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                                                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                                                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="green" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                                                                    Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                                <RowStyle BackColor="#c9d9c9" Font-Size="Small" />
                                                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                                                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                                                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                                                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
                                                                <Columns>
                                                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Agency Name" DataField="Name" 
                                                                        ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="True"></ItemStyle>
                                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" 
                                                                        ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="True"></ItemStyle>
                                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contact Name" DataField="ContactName" 
                                                                        ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="True"></ItemStyle>
                                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contact Phone" DataField="Phone" 
                                                                        ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="True"></ItemStyle>
                                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                                    </Columns>
                                                                </asp:GridView>
                       <asp:Button ID="btnAddAgency" Text="Add Agency" runat="server" />
                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgencySearch" runat="server" />
                       <asp:Button ID="btnSearchAgency" runat="server" Text="Search" />
                    </ContentTemplate>    
           </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
```

and this is my C# code that when the dropdown changes, it shows data in grid.(but grid is only visible when it is outside of the Tab, when I put in inside the Tab in disappears.

```
    protected void ddlPartnerList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Aid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPartnerList.SelectedItem.Value);
            if (Aid != 0)
            {
            Session["Aid"] = Aid;

            TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 0;


            var AgencyList = adminmv.getAgency(Aid);
            grAgency.DataSource = AgencyList;
            grAgency.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you remove the gridview and place some text in your tab, does the text show properly?

Comment: @RickS yes, it show the text.

Comment: What's in your Page_Load?  Are you doing anything with grAgency there?

Comment: @RickS no I dont have anything related to grAgency  in page load

Answer (score 0):

Put the GridView inside a ContentTemplate inside an UpdatePanel inside the ContentTemplate of the TabPanel and make sure you have a ToolkitScriptManager control on the page.

```
<tabPanel>
     <contentTemplate>
          <updatePanel>
               <contentTemplate>
                     <gridview>
```